# Can POP (Plaster of Paris) and Paint done without waiting

Tags: painting, plaster

I am undergoing paint in my house and POP at same time.

A guy did a POP in most of the rooms.

Now after how much time i allow a painter to start doing a putty and paint on it or should they wait for some time.

Overall i want to ask how much time i left POP to fully dry before painters can start doing their work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POP (plaster of paris) achieves full hardness in about 12 days at STP.  but for your purposes its entirely cosmetic.  you should be able to very safely paint 24 hrs after installation.  give it an extra 24hrs on the ceilings to be safe.  you can help things along enormously by using a dehumidifier to speed up the curing process